# How to create a form inside a bundle in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to create a form inside a bundle src/ViBillingPortal/CashPaymentBundle.
I had tried 
php app/console generate:doctrine:form ViBillingPortal/CashPaymentBundle:Post
But I got 
[InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "generate:doctrine:ViBillingPortal" namespace

Comment: which is the symfony version?

Comment: you can always use Symfony's `list` command to see all available commands or  a list of commands for a specific namesspace like `generate`

try:
`app/console list` or `app/console list generate`

Comment: What about `generate:doctrine:form CashPaymentBundle:Post`?

Comment: generate:doctrine:form ViBillingPortalCashPaymentBundle:Post